# Android Chrome HTML Canvas Arc Bug

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, canvas

Fiddle Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/j4owpexc/1/

Device Specs:

Chrome 72.0.3626.105
Android 6.0.1; Nexus 7 Build/MOB30X

On this fiddle, I create two canvases and draw some circles. The first canvas is of width 115, the second of width 439. On most devices and browsers the circles are the same. On the above version of Chrome, running on Android, the circle in the smaller canvas (the leftmost circle) renders properly, while the circles in the larger canvas (the three rightmost circles) render oddly. Here's a screenshot from my Nexus 7:

[image: rendering problems on the 3 rightmost circles]

Lines and squares etc seem to render nearly the same between the two canvases. Now, if you change the width of the second canvas to 438, it will render properly. In fact, any width less than or equal to 438 will render the circles properly, and any width greater than or equal to 439 will render them improperly.

Anybody have any idea whats going on here? I'm pretty sure this is the most current version of Chrome for Android. This has been driving me crazy for a while. On my other Android phone, running the same version of Chrome, it renders properly.

```
<html>
    <head><style>* {margin:0; padding:0;}</style></head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

<script>

    var canvas1 = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    canvas1.width = 115
    var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

    ctx1.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx1.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx1.beginPath();
    ctx1.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx1.arc(60, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx1.strokeRect(50, 50, 40, 40);
    ctx1.fillRect(60, 60, 20, 20);
    ctx1.moveTo(10, 10);
    ctx1.lineTo(40, 40);
    ctx1.lineTo(10, 80);
    ctx1.stroke();
    document.body.appendChild(canvas1);

    var canvas2 = document.createElement("CANVAS");        // Create a <button> element
    canvas2.width = 439

    var ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.arc(60, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillRect(60, 60, 20, 20);
    ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 40, 40);
    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(40, 40);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 80);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.arc(170, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.arc(280, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    document.body.appendChild(canvas2);                    // Append <button> to <body> 
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like an antialiasing issue, where antialias would fire, but pixels that should have been semi-transparent (or below a given opacity) are discarded. Write a bug report to chromium's team after you test on a different browser from same device.

Comment: And FWIW, no repro for me on a galaxy S6.

Comment: I just tested it on Firefox on the same tablet and it rendered properly there, so it must be an issue with Chrome. I'll write a bug report. Thanks for your comments.